# Grub does not start but starts through the bios

Tags: 18.04, grub2, hp, bios

I recently installed ubuntu on one of my available NVMe SSDs, on the HP Zbook G3 15, with the secure boot.

The problem is that grug starts in CLI mode with a normal boot, but passing by the bios, it boot without problem.

I installed ubuntu several times with or without the secure boot, always the same problem with ubuntu 18.04 / 18.04.1 / 18.04.2.

There are windows 10 installed on the other NVMe SSD, it was installed before ubuntu.

Grub version : 2.02/UEFI Bios

If you need more information, do not hesitate to ask

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Out :

```
Disque /dev/nvme1n1 : 238,5 GiB, 256060514304 octets, 500118192 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets                                                              
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets                                                                  
Type d'étiquette de disque : gpt                                                                                              
Identifiant de disque : 0011C4F4-7F3D-4319-A4C0-2AB445754DC9                                                                  

Périphérique     Début       Fin  Secteurs Taille Type                                                                        
/dev/nvme1n1p1    2048   1085439   1083392   529M Environnement de récupération Windows
/dev/nvme1n1p2 1085440   1290239    204800   100M Système EFI
/dev/nvme1n1p3 1290240   1323007     32768    16M Réservé Microsoft
/dev/nvme1n1p4 1323008 500117503 498794496 237,9G Données de base Microsoft


Disque /dev/nvme0n1 : 477 GiB, 512110190592 octets, 1000215216 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : gpt
Identifiant de disque : 6A5EFB44-5753-49B8-8531-2AB75C37358D

Périphérique      Début        Fin  Secteurs Taille Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1     2048     976895    974848   476M Système EFI
/dev/nvme0n1p2   976896   10741759   9764864   4,7G Partition d'échange Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p3 10741760 1000214527 989472768 471,8G Système de fichiers Linux


Disque /dev/sda : 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 octets, 976773168 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 4096 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 4096 octets / 4096 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : gpt
Identifiant de disque : 9A0B9D3E-5E69-4C7E-BCC7-4C55D5EC3D04

Périphérique Début       Fin  Secteurs Taille Type
/dev/sda1     2048 976773119 976771072 465,8G Données de base Microsoft
```

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jkGk5fMCGZ/